# Set default Global XSS filter- Session - CodeIgniter 3x

Tags: codeigniter-3

Hope someone can help me explain some of my questions in order:

### 1. When i set application/config/config.php:

> Determines whether the XSS filter is always active when GET, POST or
>   COOKIE data is encountered.
>
> $config['global_xss_filtering']  =  TRUE;

So if I set the default value is FALSE. What benefits will I get? For example, the performance or processing speed of the server?

### 2. Session

```
function save(){    
    $data = $this->input->post('number',TRUE);
    $this->session->set_userdata('TEST',$data);
}
//Suppose Client request GET to action
function insert(){
    $num = $this->session->userdata('TEST');
    //Do I need to filter data in session?    
    $num_clean = $this->security->xss_clean($num );    
    $this->model->run_insert($num_clean);
}
```

I do not trust the user. And I still do not understand much about: session activity

- The server just sends the ID Session to the client. Does the server send the data, which I set up to the session, to the client?
- Best way xss_clean for session Which i am using is: Filter the client data by xss_clean input class. Is that enough? And need to re-filter session again?

Hope someone helped me because I just using only Codeigniter's XSS filter. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

part 1:

From  CodeIgniter User Guide Version 2.2.6

> XSS Filtering
>
> CodeIgniter comes with a Cross Site Scripting Hack prevention filter which can either run automatically to filter all POST and COOKIE data that is encountered, or you can run it on a per item basis. By default it does not run globally since it requires a bit of processing overhead, and since you may not need it in all cases.
> It's not something that should be used for general runtime processing since  **it requires a fair amount of processing overhead.**

So answerto your 1st part of question : **yes** ,
setting `$config['global_xss_filtering'] = false;` has performance benefits. also in codeigniter 3 its This feature is DEPRECATED. So i prefer to set it false.

part 2 :

Session is different from cookie
Unlike a cookie, the information is not stored on the users computer. So when you store a session ,its safe to trust the session data.

session data are stored in server. Most sessions set a user-key on the user's computer that looks something like this: 765487cf34ert8dede5a562e4f3a7e12. Then, when a session is opened on another page, it scans the computer for a user-key. If there is a match, it accesses that session, if not, it starts a new session.

here is a simple guide to session to read https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp
deftailed one : http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php

in short  `$num_clean = $this->security->xss_clean($num );`  this is unnecessary.